# Mono retry with backoff not getting called for few elements in stream

Tags: java, mono, project-reactor, flux, reactor

There are stream of integers that I am trying to process. Incase of an exception I want to retry with backoff and at the same time backpressure will also be applied on the stream. I see that for few elements retry is not getting called.

To reproduce execute the below code and you should see code will be waiting indefinitely because queue becomes full coz for few elements doFinally is not called. In this case we should see count as 2000 but it will be less.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import reactor.util.retry.Retry;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;

public class MonoRetryTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonoRetryTest.class);

    private static BlockingQueue blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque(30);
    private static final List values = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Integer>());

    @Test(timeout = 30000)
    public void testMonoRetryWithBackOff() {

        Flux.range(0,2000)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .flatMap(e -> monoUtil(e))
                .blockLast();

        int processedValues = values.size();
        Assert.assertTrue("Signal not recieved for all elements", 2000 == processedValues);
    }

    private static Mono monoUtil(int val) {
        return Mono.just(1)
                .flatMap(e -> {
                    try {
                        blockingQueue.put(val);
                    } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                        interruptedException.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return serviceCall(Mono.just(val));
                })
                .doFinally(e -> {
                    blockingQueue.remove(val);
                    values.add(val);
                    logger.info("Finally Called "+ val);
                });
    }

    private static Mono serviceCall(Mono<Integer> responseMono) {
        return responseMono
                .map(response -> test(response))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(10)))
                .onErrorReturn("Failed");
    }

    private static String test(Integer value) {
        if(value%5 == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception");
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like program causes deadlock . Can try `Schedulers.elastic()` instead of `Schedulers.parallel()`

Comment: @AjitSoman where do you see dead lock in this code? I am trying to understand the way reactor process backoff is different and if it is causing deadlock?

Comment: I am 90% sure , The operation on blockingQueue is causing deadlock